# Compare File Hash in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filehash, get-filehash

I'm very new to Powershell, but am attempting to write a simple function to compare two files using their hashes. I'm getting some unexpected results using the following :

```
$hash1 = Get-FileHash $source | Select-Object Hash
Write-Host("    hash1 : " + $hash1)
```

returns : hash1 : @{Hash=93725215281E09E21317EA88E03B246AE13890ED96BB0B842A05A5E4969A4BFA}

```
$hash2 = Get-FileHash $destination | Select-Object Hash
Write-Host("    hash2 : " + $hash2)
```

returns : hash2 : @{Hash=93725215281E09E21317EA88E03B246AE13890ED96BB0B842A05A5E4969A4BFA}

```
$hashdiff = ($hash1 -eq $hash2)
Write-Host("   hashdiff : " + $hashdiff)
```

returns : hashdiff : False

I'm sure it's an obvious mistake, but can somebody put me out of my misery and help me understand why the equality operator isn't working as expected?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines `Get-FileHash $source | Select-Object Hash` (same for `$destination`) return PSObjects containing a **property** `Hash`.

It's that property you want to compare, so either do

```
$hashdiff = ($hash1.Hash -eq $hash2.Hash)
```

Or get the hash string values and compare those:

```
$hash1 = Get-FileHash $source | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
Write-Host("    hash1 : " + $hash1)

$hash1.gettype().fullname
$hash1

$hash2 = Get-FileHash $destination | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
Write-Host("    hash2 : " + $hash2)

$hashdiff = ($hash1 -eq $hash2)
Write-Host("    hashdiff : " + $hashdiff)
```

Result:

> ```
> hash1 : 6A9F599704B0895581ED47805F80137120D14E824DA19A78C2808576A8A0405B
> hash2 : 6A9F599704B0895581ED47805F80137120D14E824DA19A78C2808576A8A0405B
> hashdiff : True
> ```

Comment: ... for brevity, you can replace `Get-FileHash $source | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash` with `(Get-FileHash $source).Hash`